# When using Core Services, how do you Localize or UnLocalize a component without a fatal error when the item is already in that state?

Tags: tridion

I am using `CoreService2010Client`, I am iterating through a list of TCM ID values I have and either localizing it or unlocalizing it. Sometimes the item is already localized, so when I call `client.Localize();`, it throws an exception saying "The item is localized.".

How do I test the state of the component (localized or not-localized) before I try to change it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you will need to open a ComponentData object as follows:

ComponentData usedComponentData = (ComponentData)client.Read(uriUsedItem, new ReadOptions());

Then check usedComponentData.BluePrintInfo.IsLocalized which will return a Boolean value

Comment: Who can put in a suggestion for adding TryLocalize & TryUnLocalize methods?

Comment: You can file an ER though Customer Support or http://ideas.sdltridion.com/ but I can't see them doing it given that we can easily put a try catch around the call or check if the item is already localized. The same story would be true for almost all actions like CheckOut, CheckIn, UnLocalize etc - It would result  in a lot of extra service methods.